# Merge into one query two distincts

Tags: laravel

How do I need to make this into one query?

```
 $yearsInvoices = ModelOne::query()
      ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(YEAR(date)) as year'))
      ->groupBy('year')
      ->pluck('year')
      ->toArray();

  $yearsExpenses = ModelTwo::query()
       ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(YEAR(date)) as year'))
       ->groupBy('year')
       ->pluck('year')
       ->toArray();

  $years = \array_merge($yearsExpenses, $yearsInvoices);
```

Would appreciate some help. It's possible to join those two tables like this:

```
->join(modeltwo_table, modeltwo_table.c_id, modelone_table.c_id)
```

What I had:

```
 $yearsInvoices = ModelOne::query()
      ->join(modeltwo_table, modeltwo_table.c_id,'=', c_id)
      ->select([
          DB::raw('DISTINCT(YEAR(date)) as modelone_year'), 
          DB::raw('DISTINCT(YEAR(modeltwo_table.date)) as modeltwo_year')
      ])
      ->groupBy('modelone_year')
      ->groupBy('modeltwo_year')
      ->pluck('modeltwo_year', 'modelone_year')
      ->toArray();
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: "But it didn't work." did it throw an error or did it not return any results?

Comment: ```SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(YEAR(modeltwo_table.date)) as modeltwo_year```

Comment: Can you show us the generated SQL query? You can do that with `->toSql()`.

Comment: ```select DISTINCT(YEAR(date)) as modelone_year, DISTINCT(YEAR(expenses.date)) as modeltwo_year from `invoices` inner join `expenses` on `expenses_company_id` = `company_id` where `invoices`.`company_id` = ? and `invoices`.`deleted_at` is null and `is_draft` = ? group by `modelone_year`, `modeltwo_year`  
``` modeltwo_table = `expenses` and modelone = `invoices` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the way you use DISTINCT doesn't work because Laravel will generate invalid SQL syntax. Try something like this:

```
$yearsInvoices = ModelOne::query()
      ->join(modeltwo_table, modeltwo_table.c_id,'=', c_id)
      ->select('YEAR(date)) as modelone_year', 'YEAR(modeltwo_table.date)) as modeltwo_year')
      ->distinct()
      ->groupBy('modelone_year')
      ->groupBy('modeltwo_year')
      ->pluck('modeltwo_year', 'modelone_year')
      ->toArray();
```

Just after writing this answer I realized that there was probably a simpler way, try this:

```
 $yearsInvoices = ModelOne::query()
      ->join(modeltwo_table, modeltwo_table.c_id,'=', c_id)
      ->select(
          DB::raw('DISTINCT YEAR(modelone_table.date) as modelone_year, YEAR(modeltwo_table.date) as modeltwo_year'))
      ->groupBy('modelone_year')
      ->groupBy('modeltwo_year')
      ->pluck('modeltwo_year', 'modelone_year')
      ->toArray();
```

Comment: First solution error ```Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'YEAR(date))' in 'field list'```, second solution error: ```Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous```

Comment: Could you try the second one again? I updated it. "date" was used instead of "modelone_table.date".

Answer (score 2):

What could work for you would be some sort of a union:

```
  $yearsInvoices = ModelOne::query()
      ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(YEAR(date)) as year'));

  $yearsExpenses = ModelTwo::query()
       ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(YEAR(date)) as year'));
  
  $allYears = DB::table($yearsInvoices->union($yearsExpenses))
            ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(year) as year'))
            ->pluck('year')->toArray();
```

This creates the union query (which will concatenate the two result tables), then uses the resulting union as the target for a new select which itself will select distinct years from this union resulting in (hopefully) all distinct years in each table